# Converting a variable length csv value column to another table

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I have a doubt, I've stored comma separated values in a column with each value representing a letter of a alphabet, so the csv value represents a word.

| P.K | COLUMN | Meaning (not in table) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `4,15,7` | `d,o,g` |
| 2 | `2,9,18,4` | `b,i,r,d` |

I was told tihs is poor database design and I must store the csv column as a separate table

but if I do so, I can't account for the variable length of the value, for example one word can be of three letters and the other of 4
So what do I do should I make a table with some absurdly large number of columns like 24 to put those values or is there some other way to go about it

I'm doing all this so I could analyze each letter like its position in the word and the frequency of occurrence throughout the records

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Dai I'm using MySQL

Comment: Why are you storing this data in a database table in the first place? Is this for a personal or pet project? Will you be manipulating the data in-memory (think: Python, pandas,  R, etc) or do you intend to use SQL to _query_ your data and perform joins and set operations? Is there a reason you're not just using flat-files on-disk?

Comment: @Dai Its for a website I'm creating. It's a school project. To find out the frequency of the text I plan to retrieve the records where a letter occurs and calculate it and I'm planning to do these with queries alone and for other work like calculating the position of each letter I think I will use some frontend javascript code. I just went with a MySQL without putting much though to it, so there's no reason I'm not using flat-files-on-disk

Comment: If you're learning relational databases I would suggest you read a [normalisation tutorial](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/database-normalization-tutorial/), storing delimited data as strings violates first-normal form and has no place in a relational database.

Comment: @Stu _"storing delimited data as strings violates first-normal form"_ - yes, but the OP's data is not a good candidate for representing in Codd's relational model anyway. I see nothing wrong with using an RDBMS as a quick-and-dirty key-value-store as in this case.

Comment: @dai sure in this case that's probably true, we've all done quick-and-dirty! *knowing* that's what it is though is also important imho especially when learning something new, best to avoid something that might bite you later on. if you can

Comment: @Stu This got me thinking... are there any "micro-object servers" out there? something like a traditional RDBMS server, but intended to retain arbitrary _but small_ object-graphs and perform operations on them - nothing as hefty as GraphQL: I'm thinking more like first-year CS student homework C89 linked-lists and so on, or a persistent trie structure or similar...